# Sessão no Forms

Tags: python, django

## O que eu fiz

Tenho uma view que chama um template com um formulário. Em um determinado caso, preciso salvar alguns dados no escopo de sessão e mandar para outra url - que irá chamar outra view e outro template.

## Meu Problema

Eu criei a sessão e fiz o redirecionamento pra URL. Essa URL está apontando pra `MinhaSegundaView`, que chama um form e template diferente. Eu fiz um teste e exibi os dados da sessão no template utilizando a sintax `session.order_id`, e queria fazer o mesmo no meu form `FormDois`, pois uso-o para a construção dos inputs no template. Porém, caso eu coloque no `initial` o `request`, ele diz que esse elemento não existe. Creio eu por ele não ter acesso ao objeto de requisição.

O que posso fazer ?

## Meu Código

#### Views.py

```
class MinhaView()
    template_name = 'arquivo.html'
    form_class = FormUm

    def post()
        request.session['order_id'] = order_id
        HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_email'))

class MinhaSegundaView()
    template_name = 'arquivodois.html'
    form_class = FormDois

class FormDois(forms.Form):
    order_id = forms.CharField(label=u'Pedido', initial=request.session['order_id'], required=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse problema está acontecendo porque o seu form não tem 'request'. A sua requisição acontece na view, quando você chama um form, não existe o envio do request ou qualquer parâmetro para ele.

A primeira coisa a ser feita, é um **init** para o seu formulário:

```
class FormDois(forms.Form):
        order_id = forms.CharField(label=u'Pedido', required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormDois, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['order_id'].initial = kwargs['initial']['order_id']
```

E para utilizar class based view, é importante que você saiba como as coisas são implementadas. Se abrir o código do django e visualizar a implementação que é utilizada para o form_class, verá que nele existe um cara chamado "get_initial", ou seja, ele pega as informações iniciais. Com isso você pode fazer um override desse cara:

```
class MinhaSegundaView(View):
    template_name = 'arquivosdois.html'
    form_class = FormDois

    def get_initial(self):
        return { 'order_id': self.request.session['order_id'], }
```